# curl Unfortunately,your operating system distribution and version are not supported by this script

Tags: citus

my operating system is rocky8.5。when i execute “curl https://install.citusdata.com/community/rpm.sh | sudo bash”，tell me “Detected operatiog system as rocky/8 Unfortunately,your operating system distribution and version are not supported by this script”.can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message suggests, we don't release packages for this OS; but building Citus from the source would help if this is applicable to you.

Comment: thank you. to build Citus source myself ?

Comment: building & installing citus extension from the source code, by following this link: https://github.com/citusdata/citus/blob/v10.2.5/CONTRIBUTING.md